# PyWin32, Excel and "doing no damage" to the existing system

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I've got a Python pyWin32 application opening an excel file, hiding the excel application, and doing work on it.  When it's done, it closes the application.  Everything works great unless i already have an Excel instance running.  In that case, it hides my already running excel application and i'm forced to go find it in the task manager ultimately killing it with "end task".  Is there a way to open a separate instance of excel and "do no damage" to my current environment.  Or perhaps another approach?

```
excelapp = win32com.client.Dispatch( "Excel.Application" )
app.Visible = 0
exceldoc = excelapp.Workbooks.Open( excel_doc_path )
...
# do work on file
...
exceldoc.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DispatchEx()` to start a new instance.